# What are the difference between an array with square brackets vs one with double quotes, specifically in EXIFtool?

Tags: php, arrays, exiftool

I'm using [EXIFTool](https://exiftool.org/) in a PHP script to process some images. Originally, I was using the "-php" which returns data in an array like this:

```
Array
(
  [SourceFile] => 19770418_060000000_iOS.jpg
  [DateTimeOriginal] => 1977:04:18 00:00:00
  [Description] => Lake Huron Trip
  [Keywords] => Array
  (
    [0] => Lake Huron
    [1] =>  Memorial Day
    [2] =>  John Smith
    [3] =>  Janet Weiss
  )
)
```

then I found this [Stayopen](https://github.com/tsmgeek/ExifTool_PHP_Stayopen) library which significantly improves processing time but it returns the data in an array like this:

```
Array(Array(
  "SourceFile" => "19770418_060000000_iOS.jpg",
  "EXIF" => Array(
    "DateTimeOriginal" => "1977:04:18 00:00:00"
  ),
  "XMP" => Array(
    "Description" => "Lake Huron Trip",
    "Subject" => Array("Lake Huron","Memorial Day","John Smith","Janet Weiss")
  )
));
```

I don't understand this second type of array. How can I convert it to the same type as the first type?

Comment: There are no types of arrays. The difference is in display. The first one is how a variable dump displays an array and the second one actually gives a usable code for creating an array. What seems to be the real issue? Is it a problem that it's structured differently?

Comment: I know how to reference to get/set data in the top array, but I need to be able to do the same with the second display. I thought what you're saying was the case with the second set, but it didn't work to put it through eval();

Comment: I still don't fully understand what the issue is. Obviously you're processing this data in a certain way, can you include that in the question?

Comment: The second output is how exiftool has always returned data from using the `-php` option.  Did you take a look at the example in the exiftool docs on the [`-php` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#php) for how to process the output?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that the sample code I was using had "$exifarry=" prepended to the shell_exec() output inside the eval(). Your questions got me looking closer at the differences in the samples I was using.

Comment: The output from shell_exec("exiftool -php ...") is not exactly the same as Stayopen. I'm guessing there's an option for grouping data by metadata type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @El_Vanja for setting me on the right path. The second output is the definition string that would be used to create an array.

I prepended the string "$outputarray=" to that second output I was getting and ran it through eval().

Example:

```
$output = "Array(Array(
  "SourceFile" => "19770418_060000000_iOS.jpg",
  "EXIF" => Array(
    "DateTimeOriginal" => "1977:04:18 00:00:00"
  ),
  "XMP" => Array(
    "Description" => "Lake Huron Trip",
    "Subject" => Array("Lake Huron","Memorial Day","John Smith","Janet Weiss")
  )
));"
```

```
$prependstring="$outputarray=";
```

```
eval($prependstring . $output);
```

and now $outputarray has converted that output to an array, so print_r($outputarray) shows this:

```
Array
(
    [SourceFile] => 19770418_060000000_iOS.jpg
    [EXIF] => Array
        (
            [DateTimeOriginal] => 1977:04:18 00:00:00
        )
    [XMP] => Array
        (
            [Description] => Lake Huron Trip
            [Subject] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lake Huron
                    [1] => Memorial Day
                    [2] => John Smith
                    [3] => Janet Weiss
                )
        )
)
```